# PHP 'no value' for configuration file path

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm fairly new to web development and I've been trying to integrate some algorithms I have created in PHP with a mySQL database.

Upon attempting to use `mysqli_connect()`, I encountered an error stating that the function doesn't exist.

When I looked at the php.ini file via XAMPP, it showed that the mysqli extension should be activated. I then looked at `phpinfo()` and it gave the following results relating to the .ini file:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path       no value
Loaded Configuration File               (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed            (none)
```

I've got absolutely no idea what the issue is, so I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your httpd.conf add the php reference `PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/php74"`

Comment: my apache(httpd.conf) don't have that reference.

Answer (score 0):

go to your httpd-xampp.conf in xampp\apache\conf\extra. look for PHPIniDir and set it to PHPIniDir "C:/php". the last part is path to your php.ini file. save and restart server.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything or answer the question.